# What is the cause of "Error in .C("unlock solver")" Error in deSolve Package?

Tags: r

I have been using the deSolve package in a MCMC algorithm to estimate parameters in an ODE and wrote the functions used in the solver in C to speed up the algorithm.  Sometimes, but not always I get the error `Error in .C("unlock solver")` when running the `ode` function.  I am able to successfully compile and link the C files using the commands

```
system("R CMD SHLIB [insert-file-path]")
dyn.load("[dll-file-path]")
```

but when I try to solve the ODE using the dll file, the error is thrown.  Then, even when running a simple script like the one below, I get the same error.  I think the issue is related to using the compiled code, but I don't know how and cannot find any references on this error.

```
> require(deSolve)
> initVal <- c(y=1)
> times <- seq(0, 1, 0.001)
> parms <- c(k=1)
> model1 <- function(t, y, parms){
+   with(as.list(c(y, parms)),{
+     dy <- -k*y;
+     list(c(dy))
+   })
+ }
> out <- ode(y=initVal, times=times, parms=parms, func=model1)
Error in .C("unlock_solver") : 
  "unlock_solver" not resolved from current namespace (deSolve)
```

**Partial Solution**
If I restart R and only load the DLL using the `dyn.load` function, but don't compile the code, the `ode` function runs without an error.  This fixes my problem, but I still have no idea why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit:
REAL solution from Thomas Petzoldt on the R help list:

> [The error] occurs, if package deSolve is loaded after the compiled model... The solution is to load deSolve before [before loading DLL's], ideally at the very beginning of your script, and at least before loading/unloading the DLL/.so

If that doesn't work, the below might as well (old answer):

I have found a somewhat inelegant solution.

The problem seems to be that the "unlock_solver" function within deSolve is somehow not being accessed correctly. You can unload and reload the entire deSolve.so file, rather than restarting R.

To do this you can use something like:

```
require(deSolve)

# encounter error

library.dynam.unload("deSolve", libpath=paste(.libPaths()[1], "//deSolve", sep=""))
library.dynam("deSolve", package="deSolve", lib.loc=.libPaths()[1])
```

You'll need to replace ".libPaths()[1]" with wherever you have installed deSolve, if it isn't in the first element of your .libPaths variable.

This is something of a sledge hammer, though. I've sent out a request to the r-help list asking if there is some way to either change where R looks for "unlock_solver", or to just unload/reload a portion of deSolve.

Comment: That is better than restarting R, but a fix to the package would certainly be the best scenario. Thanks for filing a request.

Comment: REAL solution from Thomas Petzoldt on the R help list:

"[The error] occurs, if package deSolve is loaded after the compiled model...

The solution is to load deSolve before [before loading DLL's], ideally at the very beginning of your script, and at least before loading/unloading the DLL/.so"

Comment: Thanks for citing my R-help answer. The solution is indeed the "REAL" solution to load the package before loading the DLL. It is anyway common (and I would say good) practice to load all required packages at the beginning of an R script.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following packages installed (at the beginning of your script) to compile the .dll file.

```
packages <- c("deSolve","coda", "adaptMCMC")  
if(require(packages)){
    install.packages(packages,dependencies = T)
  }
ppp <- lapply(packages,require,character.only=T)
```

First remove the current .dll file in your wdir

```
c_compile <- "your_c_file"
dyn.unload(paste0(c_compile,".dll")) # unload dll (Windows only)
```

Then compile the C file and the .dll

```
system(paste0("R CMD SHLIB ",c_compile,".c"))
dyn.load(paste0(c_compile,".dll"))# Load dll (Windows only)
```